# How to fix lexical error in GetOldTweets in R?

Tags: r, json, web-scraping, twitter, collections

I'm trying to get historical tweets using [GetOldTweets in R](https://github.com/sarikayamehmet/GetOldTweets-R):

```
library(rtweet)
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)

my_app <- rtweet_app("Name of my App")

auth_as(my_app)

startdate =  "2020-06-01" # A lower bound date to restrict search.
enddate = "2020-07-01"    # An upper bound date to restrist search.
language = "en"           # Tweets in a specific language to restrist search.
ntweets = 1000            # The maximum number of tweets to be retrieved
searchTerm <- "donald trump"

searchbox <- URLencode(searchTerm)
# convert to url
temp_url <- paste0("https://twitter.com/i/search/timeline?f=tweets&q=",searchbox,"%20since%3A",startdate,"%20until%3A",enddate,"&l=",language,"&src=typd&max_position=")
webpage <- fromJSON(temp_url)
```

At this point, this error appears:

```
Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
  lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <!DOCTYPE html> <html dir="ltr"
                     (right here) ------^
```

What does this error mean? How can I fix it?